Are Firestore rules supported server-side?
In my experience, the simple answer is "no" - but I'd appreciate confirmation.
Client-side, I use the Firestore Client SDK and Firestore rules to manage my Firestore database.  This works fine.
Server-side, I can continue to use the Firestore Client SDK but all read/write requests are rejected here if meaningful Firestore rules are present (ie anything other than "allow read, write"). This behaviour persists even after logging a user in on the client, passing a uID to an authorised server, and decoding it.
The alternative is to forget about Firestore rules, authenticate the server code with a service account and manage authenticate database use in code rather than through Firestore rules.
This too works fine but niggles because I'm now doing the same thing in two different ways. It appears that server-side you have to re-interpret your Firestore rules in code and accept the need to use Firestore Admin SDK database commands rather than Client SDK commands.
Firestore rules aren't supported here and attempts to use them trigger errors.
Am I missing something?


It appears that server-side you have to re-interpret your Firestore rules in code and accept the need to use Firestore Admin SDK database commands rather than Client SDK commands.

Yes, this is the way things work. Security rules are necessary for client code because the client can be compromised or malicious in some way - you just don't control the way the code executes.  This isn't a problem on backends where you are in full control, so your code can be trusted to do the right thing.

Thanks Doug. Great to have this confirmed. It's starting to become important to have full clarity on this point. Svelte is pushing use of server-side code for form-handling etc and I'm finding myself writing (and debugging) much more code here than in the past.

Firebase Model:
You are right! Mainly what Firebase focuses on is to be the backend and database of your application. It is based on the model where you will directly interact with the firebase from the client-side. This is the how firebase authentication and security rules are supposed to work (you make request to Firebase from Client side).
Firebase Authentication:
Now if we are requesting to firebase from a server, then Firebase authentication won't work, even though you have the client signed in to Firebase. Its because when we sign in with firebase at client side, firebase stores a auth cookie there, so now with every request from User, that auth cookie will be passed along to identify the user who is making this req. But in case of req from a server component, that cookie is not there, so request is considered from an unsigned user.
Approach we can use:
Now to manage this, what we can do is (as you suggested) that handle user's authentication and authorization at client side, in a way that we make sure that clients accessing our certain Firebase function at server are eligible or not. Then at Firebase security rules we wont be needing sign-in authentication rules such as request.auth.uid!==null, Now we should only handle validations about the Data that is being added or modified.
Conclusion:
There is absolutely nothing wrong to connect with Firebase directly at client side, but If you do from a server then Authentication and authorization at client side, requests to firebase at server side and in security rules only handle checks on data.
